# Best practices when it comes to extending Service collections in .NET for dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Most of the information that I can find online is about how to do basic dependency injection in the common flows. eg one DI container where services are registered.

For a project we are writing a library that comes with internal services and public services. The public services are the ones providing methods that can be consumed by who used the lib.

I have written a Service extension for the internal services where they are registered. We have a separate extension for the data access, as this will be a lib on itself. My initial thought was to register all other services in the Extension. A team member offered the idea of creating another extension, for the public services, where we register the other extension + the public services. They also offered the idea to even make an extension per public service.

I was wondering if there are best practices around this and what these are. Creating an extension per public service seems a bit excessive to me. And I am not entirely sure I can see the benefit of making one specifically for the public services, as both public and internal service classes are in the same lib.

In the end, the people using the lib will simply have to add one line to their DI container (eg .UseLib() or something like that), so this is more of an internal plumbing issue.

To add more context, currently our solution is structured to have a project per service. These projects are then divided up under folders.

Internal

- service x
- service z
  ..

Public

- service a
- service b
  ..

Testing

- service x tests
- service z tests
  ..

Most of the code inside of the extensions is simply registering the services.

So the question I have is purely on best practices on having just one extension VS multiple, along with benefits/ downsides of these approaches and the one I use right now.

Comment: *"In the end, the people using the lib will simply have to add one line to their DI container (...) so this is more of an internal plumbing issue."*  - Does this mean that you could rework the plumbing later without users even noticing?  If so, then I don't see it matters either way, and you may be falling into the trap of [Bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality).  As long as you're easily able to write enough tests around the library to make it easy to rework/refactor the internals, then I would choose whatever seems easiest and stick to KISS + YAGNI principles.

Comment: @BenCottrell Yes it would only mean they need to update the package and there would be no difference at all aside of that. 

This is more for 'doing it the right way' the first time around as there won't necessarily be time in the foreseeable future to come back to the project and refactor it.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'right way'?    If it works and has no impact on your users, then why does it matter?    And if nobody is ever going to come back to revisit the code (presumably because it works and it does the job), then I would also ask why it matters?

Comment: @BenCottrell I mean the most correct way according to best practices, so that if any dev comes to it, it makes the most sense. 

We are currently doing a refactor and taking bad code and turning it into as good of code as we can get. But I can see your point, and we might be overthinking this a bit too much haha

Comment: I would make sure that the tests have you covered on that front;  realistically the only "bad code" (i.e code which developers will likely struggle with in the future) is that which isn't covered by comprehensive *behavioural* tests (tests with well-defined use cases), in which case the internal structure generally won't be a significant factor when they have tests to provide all the context and support they'll need.   (They're realistically more likely to have trouble if there are missing use cases or if they stumble over tests that are testing the wrong thing)